# complement of lexical verb 'dare'

Tags: infinitives, complements, semi-modals, lexical-verbs

> "Never mind that, do you think he remembers what You-Know-Who looks like?"     
>       Their mother suddenly became very stern. "I forbid you to ask him, Fred. No, ***don't you dare***. As though he needs reminding of that on his first day at school." 
>       "All right, keep your hair on." 
>   (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

***Don’t you dare*** is an idiom showed in [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/don%27t+you+dare#dare_1__33) and *dare* can be stranded, says CGEL (p.110).  But when you say a directive not to do something like ***don’t you dare ask him about it***, the complement of *dare* needs only to be an bare infinitive, not permitting ***don’t you dare to ask him about it***? ([OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/don%27t+you+dare#dare_1__33) says lexical verb *dare* can have to-infinitive or bare infinitive.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is correct.

*Dare* can't make up its mind whether it's a full modal, taking a bare infinitive, or a lexical verb taking a marked infinitive catenate. My impression  (it's no more than that) is that in speech the modal use with the bare infinitive is more common in negative expressions (*Don't you dare eat that apple*) and the lexical use with the marked infinitive is more common with positive expressions (*If you dare to eat that apple ...*)—except in the fixed expression *I dare say* (often written *I daresay*). But in speech positive uses are pretty rare anyway. In literary texts there is a distinct preference for the modal use.

In the 'challenge' sense (*I dare you to eat that apple*) the marked infinitive is obligatory because *dare* is unambiguously non-modal: the infinitive has a distinct subject.

Comment: the OP did not ask a question. What is the inferred question you are answering?

Comment: @BrianHitchcock OP asks whether she understands correctly that *dare* takes a marked infinitive with positive statements but acts as a modal, taking a bare infinitive, with negatives.